# How to implement ViewPage onTouch?

Tags: flutter

I've tried:

1. `onTouch` for a page widget, it works, but only after a page
   transformation finishes
2. Add a widget above `ViewPage` in the `Stack`, but how in this case handle `onTouch`
   and pass gestures to the child?

Answer (score 0):

`GestureDetector` with `HitTestBehavior.translucent` + `IgnorePointer`